# sqlite database supporting unicode and longdate

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm working on my python script to pull the data from the sqlite3 database.

When I try this code:

```
#Pull the data from the database
c = con.cursor()
channelList = list()
channel_db = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', 'source.db'))

if os.path.exists(channel_db):
   c.execute('SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs WHERE channel')
   for row in c:
       channel = row[0], row[1],row[2], row[3]
       channelList.append(channel)
       print channel
   c.close()
```

I will get the list of data with unicode `u` and long date `L` like this:

```
20:52:01 T:5212  NOTICE: (u'101 ABC FAMILY ', u'Reba -  Location, Location, Location', 20140522133000L, 20140522140000L)
20:52:01 T:5212  NOTICE: (u'101 ABC FAMILY ', u'Reba -  Your Place or Mine', 20140522140000L, 20140522143000L)
20:52:01 T:5212  NOTICE: (u'101 ABC FAMILY ', u"Reba -  She's Leaving Home, Bye, Bye", 20140522143000L, 20140522150000L)
20:52:01 T:5212  NOTICE: (u'101 ABC FAMILY ', u'Boy Meets World -  No Such Thing as a Sure Thing', 20140522150000L, 20140522153000L)
```

I want to print the data without the `u` and `L` strings.

Could you please tell me how I can print the data without the `u` and the `L` strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are printing a `tuple`, the elements of which will be printed using [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) instead of [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__). To get each to be printed in a more natural way, try:

```
print row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]
```

**Explanation by example:**

```
>>> print u'Hello'
Hello
>>> print (u'Hello', u'World')
(u'Hello', u'World')
>>> print u'Hello', u'World'
Hello World
```

**Converting:**

If you're interested in converting the data so that the strings are no longer unicode, and the dates are `int`s instead of `long`s, you can do the following:

```
>>> channel = row[0].encode('ascii'), row[1].encode('ascii'), int(row[2]), int(row[3])
>>> print channel
('101 ABC FAMILY ', 'Reba -  Location, Location, Location', 20140522133000, 20140522140000)
```

Beware that [encoding to ascii](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) will fail if the string contains a non-ascii character, by raising a `UnicodeDecodeError`. Casting the `long` to `int` will never raise an exception, but the result will simply be another `long` if the number is too large to be stored in an `int`. [More about Python's `long`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/).

**Text factory:**

Another option is to use a sqlite3 feature called [`text_factory`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.text_factory). Do this before the `c.execute`:

```
con.text_factory = lambda x: x.encode('ascii')
```

This will be automatically called when retrieving any text columns. Note that in this case, the `UnicodeDecodeError` will be raised by `c.execute` if the text can't be decoded properly.